# Assigned To error for SP 2010 / IE 10

Tags: 2010, form, internet-explorer

I am seeing and issue that is specific to SharePoint 2010 and Internet Explorer 10.

In this configuration, if I try to use the book icon of the Assigned To field to select people, I am getting an error. If I just type the names in the field, everything works fine.

I have been able to replicate the error on 3 different, unrelated environments, so I assume this is a Microsoft bug.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that full IE10 support for SharePoint 2010 will be arriving with SP2.  On a test farm, you can download SP2 from connect.microsoft.com and try to replicate it with IE10.

Comment: @TrevorSeward very useful info, thanks! Do you know where I could find more info on SP2 (for example release date)?

Comment: Release date is not announced.  All of the information available for SP2 will be on the Connect site (https://connect.microsoft.com/office/program7722).

Comment: @TrevorSeward ok. How about posting your replies as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 SP2 will provide full IE10 support.  The beta is currently available at https://connect.microsoft.com/office/program7722.  Note that you cannot upgrade from the beta to RTM.

Comment: Sorry, I am getting an error with the link (Page Not Found).

Comment: Try going to connect.microsoft.com, then looking for the Microsoft Office program.